# How do I insert something into multiple strings?

Tags: python, string, numpy, jupyter

I have 12 different strings that I want in a tuple format because I will use the strings later in a graph.
How do I add the same string into the array of strings?

I have these months:
January, February etc. and I want to insert into each string "January LSDS", "February LSDS", etc.

I tried this but I get an error:

```
insert = 'LSDS'

month_names = ('January {}', 'February {}','March {}','April {}', 'May {}', 'June {}', 'July {}', 'August {}', 'September {}', 'October {}', 'November {}', 'December {}').format(insert)

print(month_names)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-167-c79c038f3ebc> in <module>
      3 insert = 'LSDS'
      4 
----> 5 month_names = ('January {}', 'February {}','March {}','April {}', 'May {}', 'June {}', 'July {}', 'August {}', 'September {}', 'October {}', 'November {}', 'December {}').format(insert)
      6 
      7 print(month_names)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inserted = [month.format(insert) for month in month_names]
```